# Finish previous activities on button clicked android

Tags: java, android

My android app has 3 screen.

- Screen 1 (Home Screen)
- Screen 2
- Screen 3

Screen 1 starts Screen 2 and screen 2 starts screen 3.

I have added a button named **EXIT** on screen 3. What I want is when user press this button,  Screen 1 and Screen 2 activities should get finished.

Comment: you wanted to exit the app or empty your activity stack ??

Comment: when you pass intent to another activity finish first activity.like               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen2.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();                                                                           you write this code in screen1.class so Screen1 is finish there activity.tell me it is working.

Comment: And what should happen to screen 3 on press of exit button?

Comment: Actually I want to exit app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the **Exit** button in your screen 3 you might start another activity which will kill all other activities in the stack and will close itself. Here's my working sample to do the trick.

```
public class ExitActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    public static void exitApplication(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExitActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

So you need to call `exitApplication` function in your Exit button `onClick`.

Comment: Thanks brother for help

Answer (score 0):

on exit button click write the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear all the previous activities.

Comment: Suppose `Home` activity is screen three then it will clear activity stack and *restart* the activity, it's workaround but not exact solution.